# Confidence interval for expected value of variable in linear model R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have uploaded a dataset and fit a linear model to it where `y`is the predictor, `x` is the response, and `d` is the dataset.

Comment: Unclear.  Confidence interval on the mean value of Y across the data set? What does "predictive interval for just y" mean?  By definition, the expected mean value of Y will be occur at E(x), so you might try: `predict(linmod, newdata=data.frame(x=mean(d$x)), ...)`

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I am trying to find the confidence interval for the expected value of y and the predictive interval for y (not the predictive interval for the expected value of y). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a confidence interval for the point estimate like this:

```
CI <- confint(linmod, 'x', level=0.95)
```

You can generate a prediction interval for each of the observed points in d like this:

```
PI<-predict(linmod, interval="prediction", newdata = list(d$x), level=0.95)
```